# Не верный селект? sqlite

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

Пишу не большого бота с базой sqlite. В базе две таблицы: `products` и `categories_to_subcategories`. Когда запускаю такой запрос

```
select subcategory_from_category from categories_to_subcategories where category_id = 1
```

в редакторе sql все хорошо и выдает то что прошу. Когда же запускаю в JDBC пишет:

> java.sql.SQLException: no such column: 'categories_to_subcategories'

Вот дао:

```
public ArrayList<String> getSubCategoryOfCategory(String category){
    ArrayList<String> categories = new ArrayList();
    String s;
    try {
        PreparedStatement ps = getConnection().prepareStatement("select subcategory_from_category from categories_to_subcategories where category_id = ?");
        ps.setString(1, category);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
            s = rs.getString("categories_to_subcategories");
            categories.add(s);
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ProductDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return categories;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю у вас ошибка в текущей строчке

```
s = rs.getString("categories_to_subcategories");
```

замените categories_to_subcategories на subcategory_from_category

Comment: Невнимательность мой бич=)

Comment: Бывает, будьте внимательнее...